Clarifying “bring” in 1 Thessalonians 4:14
This is a question on what “bring” means and its implications on the understanding of a rapture passage.
In 1 Thessalonians 4:13-14 (LSB):


But we do not want you to be uninformed, brothers, about those who are asleep, so that you will not grieve as do the rest who have no hope.
For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so God will
bring with Him those who have fallen asleep in Jesus.


I interpret this passage as the end result of the rapture, when God will “bring” Jesus, along with the Church, to Heaven.  The living are probably not mentioned initially because the Thessalonians are mainly interested in the dead (v13).
If this is the beginning (as some interpret), I think the verb would be “send”.   For God to initially “bring” Jesus and the dead, God would need to leave Heaven and go to the clouds above Earth (for Jesus) and then bring the dead to Earth, in the process of bringing.  This doesn’t sound correct to me.
If this is the last part of the rapture: 1) v14 does not support the idea that the dead are in Heaven with Jesus before the rapture, and that God will “bring” Jesus to the clouds and “bring” the dead to Earth to subsequently rise.  2) God in Heaven “brings”, through His power, Jesus and the Church to Him after the rapture, with the dead possibly on Earth prior to the rapture.
In summary, a detailed discussion of the limitations of “bring” is requested, and whether it influences the interpretation of timing (beginning or end of rapture) and “location” of the dead prior to the rapture.
Edit: God in Heaven brought Israel out of Egypt.  God was in neither the starting nor ending place.  In the case in 4:14, God and Jesus are both in Heaven - the same location.  “Send” wasn’t used. Why?

The undisputed text of 1 Thess 4:14 is:

εἰ γὰρ πιστεύομεν ὅτι Ἰησοῦς ἀπέθανεν καὶ ἀνέστη, οὕτως καὶ ὁ θεὸς
τοὺς κοιμηθέντας διὰ τοῦ Ἰησοῦ ἄξει σὺν αὐτῷ. = For if we
believe/trust that Jesus died and rose again, so also, through Jesus,
God will bring with Him those having fallen asleep.

The operative verb here is ἄξει = "will bring" which is future indicative active form of the verb ἄγω = I lead, lead away, bring (a person, or animal), guide, go. This is a VERY common verb in the NT with a range of meaning.
The key to understanding its meaning here is the double conjunction οὕτως καὶ = "so also"; that is, God will do the same to those having fallen asleep as was done to Jesus.  That is:

Just as Jesus died and rose again
"so also" will God "bring", ie, raise again as Jesus was raised from the dead.  Paul expands on this theme in 1 Cor 15:20-23


But Christ has indeed been raised from the dead, the firstfruit of
those who have fallen asleep. For since death came through a man, the
resurrection of the dead comes also through a man. For as in Adam all
die, so in Christ all will be made alive. But each in his own turn:
Christ the firstfruit; then at His coming, those who belong to Him.

Thus, all the faithful righteous will be treated as Christ - all the righteous will be raised when Christ returns, just as Christ was raised from the dead.

From Strong's (G71) - 'bring':
ἄγω
agō
ag'-o
"A primary verb; properly to lead; by implication to bring, drive, (reflexively) go, (specifically) pass (time), or (figuratively) induce: - be, bring (forth), carry, (let) go, keep, lead away, be open."
I believe the "lead away" definition fits best.  Christ is not actually on earth during the "caught up in the clouds" event specific to the church, the body of Christ:
1 Thessalonians 4:17

Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord.

The dead in Christ shall rise first, then anyone in Christ still living will rise next (1 Thes 4:16).  It should be noted that a believer is protected "in Christ" at the moment of belief (spiritually), but it is our new glorified bodies that will rise into the clouds, and I believe this is the time that our "hope of glory" is then realized:
1 Corinthians 15:50-54

Now this I say, brethren, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God; neither doth corruption inherit incorruption.
51 Behold, I shew you a mystery; We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed,
52 In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.
53 For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.
54 So when this corruptible shall have put on incorruption, and this mortal shall have put on immortality, then shall be brought to pass the saying that is written, Death is swallowed up in victory.

Those "in Christ" are "lead away" from earth and into the clouds to join Him.  At some point after this event, Christ will physically return to earth to establish His millennial reign for Israel's promised earthly kingdom of heaven (Acts 1:6-12). Prior to Christ's physical return, but after the "catching away" of the church, the body of Christ, Israel will experience Daniel's 70th week (their remaining prophetic seven years of tribulation) and must "endure unto the end" of it for their "taking" (Matthew 24).
